# Issue with multiple SelectItem on the DynamicForm

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm fixing UI bugs in our application and now I'm stucked with issue with multiple SelectItem on the DynamicForm.

As we know if width of pickList is not set SmartGwt ajust pickList width to fit content. The problem is when content of one SelectItem is wider then content of others. 
For example we have 2 SelectItems, **width of content from first SelectItem is less then second one**. Steaps to reproduce this issue:

1. Open first SelectItem with content with the smallest width - width of pickList is just as content
2. Open second SelectItem with content with bigger with than previous one - width of pickList is just as content
3. Open first SelectItem again - now width of pickList is the same as pickList of second SelectItem

The question is **how to force SmartGwt recalculate width of pickList for each SelectItem separately** ?

Some code example:

```java
// Constructor of our DynamicForm
public PriceItemFilterForm(DataSource datasource) {

    // SelectItem with content with the smallest width
    SelectItem priceItemType = new SelectItem(PRICE_ITEM_TYPE_NAME,
            toolMessages.priceItemTypeFilterTitle());

    // Second SelectItem with content with bigger with than previous one
    SelectItem evalTimeType= new SelectItem(EVAL_TIME_NAME,
            toolMessages.evaluationTimeFilterTitle()){
        @Override
        protected String getLocalizedMessage(String text) {
            return toolConstants.getString(text);
        }
    };
    evalTimeType.setStartRow(true);

    setFields(priceItemType, evalTimeType);
}
```

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Which version of SmartGWT are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I made an upgrade to 2.5 smart gwt version. 
And I got the same error.
I made an upgrade to 3.0 Smart GWT and there the problem was fixed !